# core.logic unification matches value in map but not key

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I don't understand why from the following two examples, the first one returns the correct value `(1)`, while the second returns `()`. I'd have expected the result `(:key)` or an exception that it can't find the solution, but not an empty list.

```
(l/run* [q]
  (l/== {:key 1} {:key q}))

;; BUT IT DOESNT WORK

(l/run* [q]
  (l/== {:key 1} {q 1}))
```

Comment: run* returns a list of solutions so () means no solutions

Comment: Agree, but to my understanding there is a solution. If you use `q = :key`, doesn't that satisfy the equation? I think we have to read the answer as: `couldn't find a solution` rather than `I can guarantee that no solution exist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found it documented as intended behaviour or not, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/logic.clj), from my (limited) understanding, it looks like unification of maps only happens with values, not keys.

As implemented in `unify-with-map*`, when `core.logic` finds the key `:key` in the first map, it looks up its value in second, doesn't find it, and so bails on the unification. Since there are no solutions, like @Arthur Ulfeldt said, you end up with `()`.

Comment: A limitation of `core.logic` in this case? But a good one to be aware of ;) My feeling is that if you extend the search space to include keys, you probably get more work to do, hence it might have to do with a performance tradeoff. To my surprise, "no solutions" in `core.logic` can just mean it can't solve it although a solution exist. So "no solution" is not a guarantee.  But still quite powerful it can unify values and that's probably what you will use anyway most of the time.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Map keys cannot be lvars.  It may not be very documented, but that was the way the feature was designed.